# Entity Framework custom type as property

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a custom type like:

```
    public class Date
    {
        public int Year {get; }
        public int Month {get; }
        public int Day {get; }

        private Date(int year, int month, int day)
        {
            // ... Year = year, Month = month, Day = day
        }

        public static Date Of(string pattern) {
           // ... to parse from pattern
           // return new Date(year, month, date);
        }

        public override string ToString(){
           // ... string like "2020-02-02"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use it in a Entity to store it in database as string:

```
public class Student{
      public string Name{get; set; }
      public Date CreateDate{get; set; }
      public DateTime CreateDate2{get; set; }
}
```

I have a `DateConverter` to covert the `Date` object to string:

```
    class DateConverter : ValueConverter<Date, string>
    {
        public DateConvertor(ConverterMappingHints? mappingHints = null) :
            base(date => date.ToString(), s => Date.Of(s), mappingHints)
        {
        }
    }
```

But I could not apply the DateConvertor.

EF Core treat Date as an Entity Type, instead of a property of an Entity.

That means:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            foreach (IMutableEntityType entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
            {
                // "Date" appears here as an Entity
                _logger.Info("Model Entity: {0}", entityType);
                foreach (IMutableProperty property in entityType.GetProperties())
                {
                     // I want "Date" appears here as a property.
                     // Actually "DateTime CreateDate2" appears here.
                     // I want my "Date" to act like "DateTime"
```

How to make custom type `Date` act like a `DateTime` as a property, instead of a entity type?

Or

How to apply `DateConverter` to my `Date`?

---

Update: This is one of the examples.
Sorry,  I could not share my real code because they belong to my company.

But the problem is the same.

I want to know how to handle all this kind of problems.
What if I have a Metadata, to store it as string (or number) in database?

```
    public class Metadata {
        public int Field1 {get; }
        public string Filed2 {get; }
        public double Field3 {get; }
        
        private Metadata(int xxx /* other params */ )
        {
            // to assign all
        }

        public static Metadata Parse (string pattern) {
           // ... to parse from pattern
           // return new Metadata(xxx);
        }

        public override string ToString(){
           // ... string like "abc.id]afe[dfe]fefa"
           // using a special encoding
        }
    }

    class MetadataConverter : ValueConverter<Metadata, string>
    {
        public MetadataConverter(ConverterMappingHints? hints = null) :
            base(data => data.ToString(), data => Metadata.Parse(data), mappingHints)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use DateTime directly? Seems like a lot of work and wasted space to use a type that can fit natively in 64bit field

Comment: As a matter of fact, there is no reason. This is only an example.Whether to use Date or DateTime is not important. I need to know the abilty of Entity Framework

Comment: Only in this situation could I use DateTime instead, no problem. But could I find out an alternate solution every time?

Comment: How about Serialize\Deserialize `Date` as json ?

Comment: @Cuppyzh Fine, but how?  But I don't think this is the point. to serialize Date as "2020-02-02" or as "{year:2020, month: 2, day: 2}". they are all string, any difference? My question is how to serialize it as string? Which interface should be implemented? not the format.

Answer (score 3):

> EF Core treat Date as an Entity Type, instead of a property of an Entity.

> Only in this situation could I use DateTime instead, no problem. But could I find out an alternate solution every time?

Rather than convert it to a DateTime, which may work in this case but not all cases, you can register your value object as a [complex type](https://entityframework.net/complex-type)

This means that EF will interpret your `Date` object as a "bag of properties" of the `Student` object that owns it, rather than as a separate entity of its own. In short, it will create a table column (in the parent entity table, e.g. `[Students]`) for every public property (day, month, year).

However, that does come with the requirement of needing to have setters on your properties and a parameterless constructor, otherwise EF cannot render your value object from the database.

In cases where there is no equivalent data type that EF can handle (such as `DateTime` for `Date`), this is the better option.

Comment: That is to say, there is no way to handle this directly. The only way to do so is to define the parameter as the type you want it to be.  If I want to store `Date CreateData` as string, I need to define it string.  Date could be appear in another object, but when I assign it to Student, it becomes string.

Comment: So Entity Framework doesn't support REAL "Custom Type".   "Custom Type" in Entity Framework means "a bag of properties" instead of "one type". This is different from what I expected as "Custom Type".

Answer (score 1):

Just configure the ValueConverter in OnModelCreating, like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    var dateConverter = new ValueConverter<Date, string>(
        v => v.ToString(),
        s => Date.Parse(s)
      ); 
    foreach (var et in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        foreach (var prop in et.GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.ClrType == typeof(Date)))
        {
            prop.SetValueConverter(dateConverter);
            //modelBuilder.Entity(et.Name).Property(prop.Name).HasConversion(dateConverter);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am afraid this solution cannot solve my problem. I have alreay mentioned this in my question.   The `Date` type doesn't appear in `var prop in et.GetProperties()`. It appears in `var et in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()`.  Date is an Entity, not a property.

Comment: What do you mean?  It's right there in the class definition as a property: `public Date CreateDate{get; set; }`.

Comment: I mean, though “ It's right there in the class definition as a property: `public Date CreateDate{get; set; }` ”, it is an entity type in `OnModelCreating` method.

Comment: As a matter of fact, what you said is just what I expected. Before I tried this, my understanding is just like yours. If you try it yourself, you may get the same shock...